# Got 404 error on tomcat 7.0.47 websocket

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans, websocket, webrtc

Hello i'm stuck with this error.
I'm always getting the 404 error, and all the stackoverflow topics where not helpfull.

I just created a simple web app called "SignalingServer" in netbeans with one endpoint class.

```
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.websocket.OnClose;
import javax.websocket.OnError;
import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
import javax.websocket.OnOpen;
import javax.websocket.Session;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;

@ServerEndpoint(value = "/endpoint")
public class WSEndpoint
{
@OnMessage
public String onMessage(String message)
{
    Logger.getLogger(WSEndpoint.class.getName()).log(Level.WARNING, "on message reached");
    return null;
}

@OnOpen
public void onOpen(Session peer)
{
    Logger.getLogger(WSEndpoint.class.getName()).log(Level.WARNING, "on open reached");
}

@OnClose
public void onClose()
{
    Logger.getLogger(WSEndpoint.class.getName()).log(Level.WARNING, "on close reached");
}

@OnError
public void onError()
{
    Logger.getLogger(WSEndpoint.class.getName()).log(Level.WARNING, "logger reached");
}   
}
```

the web xml looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <display-name>SignalingServer</display-name>
</web-app>
```

i've build the war with jdk 7 and no extra library's.

the client code is as follows
    new WebSocket("ws://10.78.40.60:8080/SignalingServer/endpoint");

firewalls are turned of and i tried deploying the webapp with the javax.websocket-api-1.0.jar and the tomcat7-websocket-7.0.47.jar. In both cases no succes. Does anybody has any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it out by myself.
I added the:
tomcat7-websocket-7.0.47.jar and the javax.websocket-api-1.1.jar to the netbeans project and it was running correctly.

It's is possible that my netbeans 7.0.47 installation is not a default installation.