# WebSocket with embedded Tomcat is 404

Tags: java, tomcat, websocket

I made two classes:

1. Main class with embedded Tomcat(8.5.20)
2. ServerEndpoint of Websocket

I run the main class on IntelliJ IDEA
and run this JavaScript: `new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080/ws')`
in the console of Google Chrome.

I expected the response code is 200, but actually it is 404.

How can I fix this?

Main class:

```
package webapp;


import org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException;
import org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import java.io.File;

public class Main {
    private static final String STATIC_DIR = "src/main/static/";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ServletException, LifecycleException {
        Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();
        tomcat.setPort(8080);

        File staticDir = new File(STATIC_DIR);
        tomcat.addWebapp("/", staticDir.getAbsolutePath());

        tomcat.start();
        tomcat.getServer().await();
    }
}
```

ServerEndpoint:

```
package webapp.websocket;

import javax.websocket.OnClose;
import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
import javax.websocket.OnOpen;
import javax.websocket.Session;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;

@ServerEndpoint("/ws")
public class SampleWebSocket {

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session) {
        System.out.println("open");
    }


    @OnClose
    public void onClose(Session session) {
        System.out.println("close");
    }

    @OnMessage
    public String onMessage(String text) {
        System.out.println("message:" + text);
        return "Server:" + text;
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I found a solution.
This question is dupricated.

I read [Got 404 error on tomcat 7.0.47 websocket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35994611/got-404-error-on-tomcat-7-0-47-websocket) and editted my pom.xml.

Following is the whole of my pom.xml.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>websocket-sample</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>websocket-sample</name>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
            <version>8.5.20</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-websocket</artifactId>
            <version>8.5.20</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.websocket</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.websocket-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just add the following dependency to `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-websocket</artifactId>
    <version>8.5.20</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

What solved the issue for me was switching from the `javax.websocket-api` dependency to the Tomcat-specific `tomcat-embed-websocket` dependency instead **and** switching all my imports (`ServerEndpoint`, `onMessage`, etc.) to the Tomcat-specific `jakarta.websocket.*` packages instead of the `javax.websocket.x` packages.

Here is the endpoint code that worked for me -- notice that there are no `javax.websocket` imports and instead I have `jakarta.websocket` imports:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import jakarta.websocket.EncodeException;
import jakarta.websocket.OnMessage;
import jakarta.websocket.Session;
import jakarta.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;

@ServerEndpoint("/echo")
public class EchoEndpoint {
    // Implementation.
    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(
        Session session, 
        String message) 
        throws 
            IOException,
            EncodeException {
        // Send the same message back.
        session.getBasicRemote().sendText(message);
    }
}
```

And my `pom.xml` file dependencies:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
    <version>10.1.0-M8</version>
</dependency>           
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-websocket -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-websocket</artifactId>
    <version>10.1.0-M8</version>
</dependency>
```

As far as I can tell, the `pom.xml` should **not** contain the `javax.websocket` dependency at all, to ensure there are no collisions/clashes between that one and the Tomcat-specific `tomcat-embed-websocket` dependency.